# Accessing funds that are sent to the smart contract address

Tags: contract-development, ether, contract-design, tokens, erc-20

If someone creates a smart contract (and is owner of that contract), is it possible for that person to collect ETH and other tokens, that are sent to the address of smart contract?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to withdraw Ether from a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25692/how-to-withdraw-ether-from-a-contract)

Comment: This is a superset from the possible duplicate as it's accessing funds like tokens, not just ETH.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible, if the creator of a smart contract *makes* it possible. If a contract does not implement any withdrawal() function, then the funds may be irretrievable by the owner.

This is a feature, not a bug. Would you want to ether delta smart contract creator to withdraw all the ether and tokens from the contract at a whim? No.

Answer (score 1):

A smart contract does not have any owner or withdrawal mechanisms unless they have been coded in the contract.  This gives smart contracts a power of being trustless: it is possible to use contracts without trusting the owner, by carefully understanding the code of the contract.

#### Withdrawing ERC-20 tokens

If you're a smart contract author, and want to be able to withdraw ERC-20 tokens, you need to do 2 steps.

Step 1: Add this interface (subset of ERC-20) above your contract

```
contract Token {
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance);
}
```

Step 2: Here is a function you can add inside your contract

```
function withdrawTokens(address tokenContract) external onlyOwner {
    Token tc = Token(tokenContract);

    tc.transfer(owner, tc.balanceOf(this));
}
```

This assumes you've correctly written and configured yourself as the `owner`.  Since your contract may receive many different types of tokens, you need to `withdrawTokens` from each `tokenContract`.  If `owner` is another contract, it must also have a `withdrawTokens` function to prevent tokens from getting stuck in the `owner` contract.

#### Withdrawing ether

The code is simpler:

```
function withdrawEther() external onlyOwner {
    owner.transfer(this.balance);
}
```

Again, if `owner` is another contract, it must also have a `withdrawEther` function to prevent ether from getting stuck in the `owner` contract.

Another reference: [How to withdraw Ether from a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25692/how-to-withdraw-ether-from-a-contract)

Comment: Thanks, so if the contract is already up, and does not have such function, are funds stuck? Can it be upgraded, so that this can be added?

Comment: @nikolaivkov Yes, funds will be stuck.  Similarly, a contract also cannot be upgraded unless it already has code allowing it to be upgraded in some way.

Answer (score 0):

**Withdrawing ether**

This function may be working with your contract correctly and let me know it working correctly or not.

```
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(success);
}
```