# How to withdraw Ether from a contract?

Tags: ether, contract-design, wallets

I am writing a smart contract which receives Ether.

How can I transfer Ether from the contract to my personal purse (non programmatically using such a program as Ethereum Wallet)?

Can I send Ether from the contract like as I can do with regular wallet?

---

In the "possible duplicate" question it is not said how to withdraw from the contract *non-programmatically*. It is should be easy for a user to withdraw, without him writing a code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to withdraw Ether from a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25692/how-to-withdraw-ether-from-a-contract)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen It is not exactly a duplicate, I have edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 6):

Basically it all depends on your contract.

Let's have an example contract:

```
contract test {
    function payme() payable public {
    }

    function getBal() public returns (uint) {
        return this.balance;
    }
}
```

You can save Ether in this contract by calling the `payme` function. Also you can query how much Ether the contract has. But the Ether can't be transferred away, so it's stuck in the contract forever.

@Victory's answer has a good idea about how to enable withdrawals without *any* coding. But that of course requires the contract to support such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this instead   :

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    uint256 amount = address(this).balance;
    require(amount > 0, "Nothing to withdraw; contract balance empty");
    
    address _owner = owner();
    (bool sent, ) = _owner.call{value: amount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
  }

  // Function to receive Ether. msg.data must be empty
  receive() external payable {}

  // Fallback function is called when msg.data is not empty
  fallback() external payable {}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are not writing a web3 interface you only have one real option and that is the default function of your contract. You would tell the user to send 0 ETH (sending 1 wei might also make sense) to the contract which would then trigger the withdraw function.

```
contract MyContract {
   uint allTheEth;

   function withdraw()
   public
   {
      msg.sender.transfer(allTheEth);
   }

   function()
   public
   payable
   {
      // user is sending nothing so they must want to withdraw
      if (msg.value == 0) {
         withdraw();
      // sender is sending something so must want to depost
      } else {
         allTheEth += msg.value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Per Lauri's answer above, you don't need to track your balance in `allTheEth`, right? You can just use `address(this).balance` ?

Comment: @Rich correct, the balance of the contract is just `this.balance`.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving Ether on smart contract is not a good idea. but if you want to do that you can make payable function to transfer the ETH.
you can find the `TransferHelper.sol` on net

```
function transferETH(address _receiverAddress) public payable {
    TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(_receiverAddress, msg.value);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why 'receiving Ether on smart contract is not a good idea'?

Comment: Because of attacks that hackers can made on smart contract and stole all your the ETH